# How do i remove outliers using multiple columns pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, outliers

Out of my entire dataframe i have two columns price and quantity. These both contain outliers. How can i remove the outliers in both these columns such that the dataframe returned excludes outliers from both these columns? I can apply it to one but not sure how i can apply it to both columns.

I've tried the below

```
def make_mask(df, column):
    standardized = (df[column] - df[column].mean())/df[column].std()
    return standardized.abs() >= 2

def filter_outliers(df, columns):
    print(columns)
    masks = (make_mask(df, column) for column in columns)
    print(masks)
    full_mask = np.logical_or.reduce(masks)
    print(full_mask)
    return df[full_mask]

outliersremoved_df=filter_outliers(df,['price','qty'])
```

I have used this but i can only apply it to one column at a time:

```
def remove_outlier(df_in, col_name):
    q1 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1 #Interquartile range
    fence_low  = q1-1.5*iqr
    fence_high = q3+1.5*iqr
    df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col_name] > fence_low) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_high)]
    return df_out
```

error with the top 2 functions:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 1)
```

Comment: lets assume ..  if you have price values is outlier and quantity is not outlier or viseversa how will you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Please use the below function which would apply on all the columns you have in #df

```
def cap_data(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        print("capping the ",col)
        if (((df[col].dtype)=='float64') | ((df[col].dtype)=='int64')):
            percentiles = df[col].quantile([0.01,0.99]).values
            df[col][df[col] <= percentiles[0]] = percentiles[0]
            df[col][df[col] >= percentiles[1]] = percentiles[1]
        else:
            df[col]=df[col]
    return df

final_df=cap_data(df)
```

Comment: i see the function above doing its job, but 
how come when i compare length of my original dataframe versus my new dataframe as an output when passed the above function, both lengths remain the same?

Comment: So basically , you can remove those rows. In the above function , we are capping them at those percentiles. In that way , we are not losing the rows , but also we have removed the outlier effects to certain extent.